# AWS Fargate with outbound static IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I have a Fargate service with one task. From this task I have to interact with a SFTP server managed by an other company, and they need to whitelist my IP.

I've already set a NLB to have a static inbound IP and it's working great, but now I need my outbound IP to static too.

I've read similar questions and they proposed the use of a NAT gateway but it's not working so far.

I have created the NAT gateway, associated it with an Elastic IP and the subnet which hosts the service but it's not working, the outbound IP is still the dynamically allocated one.

What extra steps am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have created the NAT gateway, associated it with an Elastic IP and
> the subnet which hosts the service

The NAT Gateway needs to be in a public subnet (a subnet with an Internet Gateway attached).

The service needs to be in a private subnet (a subnet with no Internet Gateway, and a route to the NAT Gateway).

The service needs "Assign Public IP" set to `false`.

Comment: Well.. that was easy enough. Thank you!